# Amerpsand format flag in java

Tags: java

I have existing java code that is used to format a string. This code fails for the below format - java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException:..Based on other SO issues, I see its more related to Java version thats used.

Question..

1. What does the '%1$#' format does..Mostly Im not able to find the '$' & '#' format rules while I googled.
2. How to fix this issue?

Java code

```
String test = String.format("%1$#" + 2 + "s", 01);
```

Comment: `java.util.Formatter` javadoc.

Comment: Where does "ampersand" come into this?

Comment: [Octothorp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#Other_names_in_English)!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of [`java.util.Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

> The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the following syntax:
>
> ```
> %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
> ```

So `%1$#2s` means an *argument_index* of 1, a *flags* value of `#` ("The result should use a conversion-dependent alternate form"), a *width* of 2, and a *conversion* of `s` (string).

For `%s` conversions, the alternate form is used by passing it to `Formattable`:

> If the argument is null, then the result is `"null"`. If the argument implements `Formattable`, then its `formatTo` method is invoked. Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking the argument's toString() method.
>
> If the '#' flag is given and the argument is not a `Formattable` , then a `FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException` will be thrown.

I suspect you don't really want `#` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about formatting [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). The error in your code is that`#` is invalid FormatFlag in your case(# mean The result should use a conversion-dependent alternate form). You can use for e.g. `s or d` to print like this

```
System.out.println(String.format("%1$d" + 2 + "s", 01));
```